# Given two coins with probability of head being p1 for coin1 and p2 for coin2. What is the pmf of Y (number of flippings to get first head)?

Tags: probability

Random variable Y is defined as:

Y = the number of flippings it takes to get the first head (flipping the randomly picked coin).

I am looking for the probability mass function of Y.

The probability of getting either coin1 or coin2 is 1/2.

Let $p=\frac{1}{2}p_{1}+\frac{1}{2}p_{2}$

So, I think the PMF of Y is

$$p_{Y}(y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\binom{n}{y}p^{y}(1-p)^{n-y} & y=1,2,3,4... \\ 
0 & otherwise 
\end{matrix}\right.$$.

I am not sure if this is correct. Can anyone tell me? Thanks.

Comment: What thoughts are behind the final expression for integer $y $?

Comment: It looks like you are finding PMF for (# heads in $n$ flips) rather than the waiting time for the first head.

Comment: I am trying to apply Binomial Random Variable here, but I don't understand the formula fully. That is why I am asking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly identified that the probability of a head on each toss is $p=\frac{1}{2}p_1+\frac{1}{2}p_2$, independently of one another. Then Y has a geometric distribution $Geo(p)$. That is, for $k=1,2,...$,
$$p_Y(k)=(1-p)^{k-1}p.$$
This is because the event that the first head comes on the $k$th flip is precisely the event that the first $k-1$ tosses are tails and the $k$th is a head. Since the flips are independent, we multiply the probabilities.

What you wrote is *almost* a binomial distribution representing the number of heads in $n$ tosses. (If you wrote $k=0,...,n$ instead of $k=1,2,3,...$)